# Windows Phone 7: How do I open the web browser?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I open a web browser in Windows Phone 7? I don't care if it is the default browser or an embedded browser, though if both are possible I would like to know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Windows Phone Forums > Windows Phone 7 > Open web browser](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/windowsphone7series/thread/ea9b464a-5486-4a96-9d78-e2f40f57b38f)

> If you want to open the built-in IE Browser then you need to use
>   WebBrowserTask object.
>
> To do this add references to Microsoft.Phone and
>   Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.  You can then launch the IE Browser using the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask(); 
> wbt.URL = "http://www.google.com";  
> wbt.Show();
> ```
>
> If you want to embed a browser window inside your application then use
>   the WebBrowser control.  Add an instance of the WebBrowser control to
>   your form then you can reference it in code using the name you give
>   it.  (Default name is "webBrowser1")

Comment: wbt.URL is Obsolete. it is better to use wbt.Uri at the moment.