# Getting a  response uri

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to Windows phone 7 application development. I'm currently developing an app in which I wish to do a HTML request and display the result obtained in Web browser. For example, Suppose I give the below URI

> "http://m.imdb.com/find?q="+search_string (where search_string is a variable)

I want to take the result obtained from this and display it on the web browser. I've been searching regarding this for past 1 day... Didn't get any fruitful results. So please redirect me either to a suitable tutorial page or please give a sample code?

Comment: Are you trying to [open a browser to a particular URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722120/windows-phone-7-how-do-i-open-the-web-browser)

Comment: No... its like i'm trying to query something using HTTP... and I want to open the result URL in browser...

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish isn't terribly clear - are you: (a) making a request via HTTP which returns a URL that you want to open in a WebBrowser or (b) want to download the content first, before displaying it in a WebBrowser?

Comment: I'm making a request via HTTP which returns a URL that I want to open in a WebBrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebBrowserTask wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
wbt.URL = "http://m.imdb.com/find?q="+search_string
wbt.Show();
```

this will allow you to launch the url in the browser.

[WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.webbrowsertask%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)